# how can i check the location of my file in my computer which i have opened in python?

Tags: python-3.x, file, pycharm

[image: this is the error i am getting]i am so much confused i am opening a file in python directly by using 
f=open('RouteDB1.dat','r')
but the content of this file is not which it is supposed to be..i think it is getting this file from some other location..and i dont know that location..if i tried with different filenames then it is showing error file not found..i am using pycharm as IDE and it is showing CWD as scratches folder..although i changed my directory to the folder i want but still i am getting file not found error..it is so frustrating..plz help [image: if i enter full path then no error..although the file i want to read and the python program file are in same folder its showing error..if i move my file to scratches..then also some files are running and some do not run]

Comment: Please help us to help you. show your code. Thanks!

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve] and edit your question accordingly.